# Adding 2 currency fields result a text field (???)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have the following problem with sharepoint 365

i have a field called "`revenues amount"` and one called `" revenues VAT"`

I created a calculated field called `"Revevenues Total"` that is the sum of the above fields `[revenues amount] + [revenues VAT]`

All the fields are CURRENCY types

the problem is that the amount i have taken seems to be a "text" field... as a result cnnot summurize (please see the print screen)

http://prntscr.com/kg7yhz

am i doing something wrong?

I would be grateful if u could help me

Answer (score 1):

What I understand, your problem is not the field itself but the "Totals" of the field "Revenues Total".

The thing is this not possible to do for a calculated field. How ever there seems to be a few people out there who has created an another calculated field and in the formula written code that summarizes the values. I cannot guarantee that this is working because I have not tested it. But I will leave you the url so you can test for your self.

So to summarize this all up, you cannot create a total sum for a calculated field without customization.

[Get the Total for Calculated Columns in SharePoint](https://www.metrostarsystems.com/enterprise-it/sharepoint-calculated-column-total/)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Calculated column cannot be available in Modify View->Totals:
[image]

So, we are unable to count Calculated column using OOB ways.
You need to check how you count the calculated column which should be the issue.